# PhpMyAdmin намертво зависает соединение при удалении строки

Tags: php, сервер, phpmyadmin

При попытки удалить любую запись в базе данных через PhpMyAdmin, намертво виснет соединение с сайтом. Ставил разные версии PhpMyAdmin, ставил и через sudo apt-get и просто заливал в папку на сайт, все время одна и та-же ошибка. При удалении записи намертво виснет соединение.

Вот данные для тестирования: http://188.226.167.251/pma/ test:12345

После удаления строки обновите страницу.

При этом запросы на удаление через php выполняются без проблем, я тестировал. В чем может быть причина? Другие решения кроме PhpMyAdmin советовать не надо, хочу просто понять в чем проблема с моей VDS.

Могу показать любые логи и конфиги, только говорите какие.

Comment: Попробовал на Вашей тестовой базе - всё нормально удаляется. Попробуйте, может быть, через другой браузер... UPD: А вот и не всегда так, попробовал ещё запись удалить - зависло...

Comment: А обновили страницу?

Comment: Всё, уже зависло, "всё в порядке"... А на сервере классический "LAMP" или какой-то особый набор софта?

Comment: Класический LEMP

Comment: А в `tail /var/log/apache2/error.log` есть что-нибудь интересное?

Comment: Заметил интересный "эффект" - если в PMA удаление выполнить не кнопкой в интерфейсе, а запросом DELETE, то ничего не зависает.

Comment: В /var/log/nginx.error.log он вообще ничего не пишет касательно этой ошибки. Очистил его, создал ошибку, размер файла 0 был так и остался.

Comment: Это я только что сервак ребутнул. После ребута он до выполнения запроса еще работает. Хотя да, реально работает вроде после DELETE FROM ручного. Мистика какае-то просто.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32732/discussion-between-dimaua-and-sergey-popov).

Comment: из чата - 
Я нашел, нашел, ошибку. Ура. Она была в моем ossec. Методом тыка я это определил. Спасибо всем!